# swiping right, the page control's current page changes but the dots don't

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a tutorial by some consequential images and added a page control on it. In addition, I added a swipe gesture which responds by changing the picture. In the code below, a switch case is defined in order to decide which image and dot should be the next according to the direction of swiping (left/right).

```
- (IBAction)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
//    NSLog(@"swiped");
    NSArray *images;

    if (self.selectedRow == 0) {
        images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"w8.JPG",@"w7.JPG",@"w6.JPG",@"w5.JPG",@"w4.JPG",@"w3.JPG", @"w2.JPG", @"w1.JPG" ,@"w9.JPG", nil];

        self.pageControl.hidden = NO;
        [self.pageControl setNumberOfPages:9];

        UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection direction = [(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender direction];

        switch (direction) {
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight:
                if (pageController == 0 || imageIndex == 8)
                {
                    self.Oops = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!" message:@"You cannot swipe to the left, there are not any previous steps." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                    [self.Oops show];
                }
                else {
                    [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:pageController - 1];
                    pageController = pageController - 1;
                }
                imageIndex++;
                break;
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft:
                if (pageController < 8 && pageController >= 0) {
                    [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:pageController];
                    pageController = pageController + 1;
                }
                else {
                    [self.pageControl setCurrentPage: pageController ];
                    pageController = 0;
                }
                imageIndex--;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        NSLog(@"pagecontroller is %li and imageIndex is %li " , pageController, imageIndex);
        imageIndex = (imageIndex < 0) ? ([images count] - 1): imageIndex % [images count];
        self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:imageIndex]];
    }
```

As you see in the code, there is a NSLog; when I run the app, everything works properly but when I swipe to the right to see a previous image, Although NSLog shows that all indexes of dots and images change correctly and we see the previous image, the dots don't change. Swiping to the right again, the dots change but it's late because the order of the images and dots that must be classified becomes disordered for example the last image is shown with the first dot.
I'm sure that my algorithm is correct, because I checked it with that NSLog, and also everything works fine before swiping to the right.
Any ideas?

I have changed the code a bit:

```
 switch (direction) {
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight:
                if (pageController != 0 && imageIndex != 9) {
                    [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:(pageController - 1)];
                    pageController --;
                    imageIndex++;
                }
                break;
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft:
                if (pageController <= 8 && pageController >= 0) {
                    [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:pageController];
                    pageController = pageController + 1;
                    imageIndex--;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Now the only problem is that the page control counts the current dot twice when I swipe to a different direction.

Answer (score 0):

Your `imageIndex++` and `imageIndex--` lines are in the wrong place.  (You presumably don't want to change image if pageController is already 0, for example).  Move them to:

```css
- (IBAction)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
//    NSLog(@"swiped");
    NSArray *images;
    
    if (self.selectedRow == 0) {
        images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"w8.JPG",@"w7.JPG",@"w6.JPG",@"w5.JPG",@"w4.JPG",@"w3.JPG", @"w2.JPG", @"w1.JPG" ,@"w9.JPG", nil];
        
        self.pageControl.hidden = NO;
        [self.pageControl setNumberOfPages:9];
        
        UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection direction = [(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender direction];
        
        switch (direction) {
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight:
                if (pageController == 0 || imageIndex == 8)
                {
                    self.Oops = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!" message:@"You should turn over to the left." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                    [self.Oops show];
                }
                else {
                    [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:pageController - 1];
                    pageController = pageController - 1;
                    imageIndex++;
                }
                break;
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft:
                if (pageController < 8 && pageController >= 0) {
                    [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:pageController];
                    pageController = pageController + 1;
                    imageIndex--;
                }
                else {
                    [self.pageControl setCurrentPage: pageController ];
                    pageController = 0;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        NSLog(@"pagecontroller is %li and imageIndex is %li " , pageController, imageIndex);
        imageIndex = (imageIndex < 0) ? ([images count] - 1): imageIndex % [images count];
        self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:imageIndex]];
    }
```

In your amended code, I think you need to set the page control differently (to pageController+1) for swipe left:

```
switch (direction) {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight:
            if (pageController != 0 && imageIndex != 9) {
                [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:(pageController - 1)];
                pageController --;
                imageIndex++;
            }
            break;
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft:
            if (pageController <= 8 && pageController >= 0) {
                [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:pageController+1];
                pageController = pageController + 1;
                imageIndex--;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Comment: I did it. Not only does the problem exist but also if we only swipe to the left, every time that you reach to the end, the last image comes to the first dot. @pbasdf

Comment: What are the starting values for pageController and imageIndex?

Comment: imageIndex is 8 and pageController is 0. @pbasdf